# pass const reference to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

I need to pass some data to following method:

```
thread::thread(_Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
```

However, my data is `const&` and there is no copy or move constructor. I am wondering how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [`std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).**

This "wraps a reference" so you bypass `std::thread`'s tendency to copy your arguments.

It then becomes your responsibility to ensure that doing so is thread-safe.

```
void foo(const int&);

int main()
{
   const int myThing = 42;

   std::thread t(&foo, std::cref(myThing));
   t.join();
}
```

This is mentioned on the cppreference page for [the `std::thread` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread):

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g., with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

… along with an example (sort of).